# Run a PHP script as a background process on a WAMP server

Tags: windows, php, background-process

I have two PHP scripts that need to be run as continuous background processes on a WAMP server.

WAMP is installed on a Windows 7 PC. These scripts are already reside in separate folder in the www root directory.

I am using the following versions of Apache and PHP:

> Apache Version :2.2.8
>
> PHP Version :5.2.6

Since this is not a Unix platform, I can't use `nohup php script.php > /dev/null` to do this job. I'm looking for similar kind of command or method which works on WAMP.

Can anyone explain the steps I need to be take to do this task?

Comment: Ignoring the WAMP component, as it is effectively irrelevant, this question is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/39451/there-is-any-way-to-run-processes-in-the-background-in-windows-nohup-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/85297/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-windows-7) and call the job using

```
...\php\cli\php.exe
```